# How to return NaN for sites which do not have crawled info?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scrapy

How can I return `NaN` for urls who do not have any: `".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]"`?. I tried to:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")
    if not links:
        item = ToyItem()
        item['link'] = 'NaN'
        item['name'] = response.url
        return item

    for links in links:
        item = ToyItem()
        item['link'] = links.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        item['name'] = response.url  # <-- see here
    yield item

    list_of_dics = []
    list_of_dics.append(item)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dics)
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/crawled_table.csv', index=False)
```

However, instead of returning `(*)`:

```
'link1.com'   'NaN'
'link2.com'   'NAN'
'link3.com'   'extracted3.link.com'
```

I got:

```
'link3.com'   'extracted3.link.com'
```

How can I return `(*)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can rework this to use scrapy pipelines:

```
from scrapy import Spider 
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['link1','link2','link3']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath(".//*[@id='object']//tbody//tr//td//span//a[2]")
        if not links:
            item = ToyItem()
            item['link'] = 'NaN'
            item['name'] = response.url
            yield item
        else:
            for links in links:
                item = ToyItem()
                item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()
                item['name'] = response.url  # <-- see here
                yield item
```

Now in your `pipelines.py`

```
class PandasPipeline:

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.data = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.data.append(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        print('saving dataframe')
        df.to_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/crawled_table.csv', index=False)
```

and for `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.PandasPipeline': 900
}
```

Comment: @tumbleweed well that means there were no links found on the page. is `parse` getting called multiple times?

Comment: Yes, for those not found links I would like to know how to impute NaN, instead of nothing `None`, saving his reference url at the left side.

Comment: dude, everytime parse is called the `to_csv` overrides the old csv with new data, so essentially you end up only having data of the last `parse` call, i.e. the last crawled link.

Comment: Yes, for those not found links I would like to know how to impute NaN, instead of nothing None, saving his reference url at the left side (in `link`) column.

Comment: I tried to fix the identation but it seems that it is actually correct.. Any idea of what can I do?

Comment: Indentation is fine, your logic is flawed here. There are two ways of fixing this, let me redo my asnwer.

Comment: Thanks Granitosaurus... I really appreciate your help... sorry I am new with scrapy..

Comment: Thanks, but I got: https://pastebin.com/kH4QXETw The weird thing is that the last link has the element I am looking for (another url)

Comment: @tumbleweed hmm, there was a typo: `item['link'] = links.xpath('@href').extract_first()` should be `item['link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()` (`link` instead of `links`). But other than that everything should work.

Comment: @tumbleweed are you sure on link3 any links are found with the xpath? You can directly check that via `scrapy shell link3` and then typing `response.xpath('some_xpath')` in the shell.

Comment: Yes, completely sure... before I start building the crawler I used the scrapy shell it returns me the link I am interested in extract.... let me rewrite my question... probably its my fault for not explaning...

Comment: I think that's the only place where the issue can be based on your output. You can try inserting `from scrapy.shell import inspect_response;inspect_response(response,self)` under parse and debug every `parse` call and make sure you are getting links when crawling `link3`.